# Azure: SKU property value for Automation Account, where are centralized Template Docs?

Tags: json, azure, templates, documentation, sku

I'm trying to deploy a Resource Group that includes an Azure Automation Account.  One of the parameters in the parameters.json file is called `automationAccounts_DSCAutomationAccount_sku`.  Putting an arbitrary string as its value results in an `InvalidTemplate` error:

> The provided value for the template parameter 'automationAccounts_DSCAutomationAccount_sku' at line '7' and
>   7' is not valid.'.

**Specific Question:** What would constitute a valid value? In powershell there is no `sku` property of the AutomationAccount object.  And when creating a new account in the Portal, there is never an option to select one of many different kinds of Automation Accounts, there is *only one kind*.  So what does Azure need an SKU field for anyway?

**General Question:** In Azure Templates (and parameter files) how can I know what a certain field expects, and what fields are required for a certain resource?  Is there any centralized doc that has all of these requirements?
It seems that there isn't, and if that's the case, that makes *authoring* templates nearly impossible, with the only viable option for producing templates being configuring a resource group in the Azure Portal, and then downloading the template JSON file that it generates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you raise a valid point, I have not seen a centralized place to look that up, but, there's a [ARM schema](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas) which is the closest to what you ask that you can get, in my opinion. But that place is a pain to navigate\look through.

Also, there's the https://resources.azure.com resource, which is really helpful, and there's the `Automation script` option on the portal, that would effectively export out the json template for you. Having said that, here's the free SKU example:

```
"sku": {
  "name": "Free",
  "family": null,
  "capacity": null
},
```

also, this seems to be the relevant schema for Automation

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/master/schemas/2015-10-31/Microsoft.Automation.json

Comment: Much thanks again, this solved the error.  Which resource did you use to find these fields and values for SKU?  The Automation part of the Schema?  I see now how I could read the schema to find these fields.  But how would I know what "name", "family", and "capacity" are referring too, and thus what values (of the available options) to assign to them?  I can't think of any corresponding values in the Portal.

Comment: I'm mostly using `https://resources.azure.com` because it is much easier to look up value for existing resource, then to browse the schema, which is next to unreadable.

Comment: This [Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com) is a great tool.  I'm surprised that I haven't even heard of it till now with all of my reading of Azure articles on MSDN and the like.