# what are the values that can be passed for sku.family and sku.capacity property in azure automation account

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-automation, azure-rm-template

Here is the link for the resources of template format for the creation of azure automation account.
what is sku , sku.family and sku.capacity for automation account?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.automation/automationaccounts/jobschedules

Normally we can create the azure automation without sku.family and sku.capacity properties.But what are the possible values that can be passed to these resources for creation of arm template.

What could be the sku.family and its corresponding sku.capacity that can be passed????

What is the use of sku.family and sku.capacity in general for azure Resources ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure: SKU property value for Automation Account, where are centralized Template Docs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574575/azure-sku-property-value-for-automation-account-where-are-centralized-template)

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT what is the use for sku.family and sku.capacity properties ??   what change does it make to the automation account??

Comment: Hi @Mohamed Meeran , Since `sku` in `properties` is a general Property values for the template format. For your case, `family ` and `capacity` do not take any effects about the automation account pricing tier. As Nancy mentioned that ,There are only two pricing tier for automation account: `Free `or `Basic`. However, for Azure VM and other services, their sku may also depends an famliy and capacity.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT . Thanks for the reply.  By the way can tell me what is the use of sku.family and sku.capacity in any other resoures ??? and can you tell me what is the use of sku.family used in the first template of the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745716/azure-arm-template-and-powershell-module?newreg=e23f1233ee3a427397b4187884dd5bf1 and how it affects the automation account (in case it affects)????

Comment: @AllTradesJack can u explain me???

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that link, we can find Sku object as pic.

[image]

Also we can [get information about an automation account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674479.aspx) ,For a Free Sku, there is a response as below:

```
"properties":{
    "sku":{
        "name":"Free",
        "family":null,
        "capacity":null
    },
```

Moreover, you can get more details from this relevant schema for Automation

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/master/schemas/2015-10-31/Microsoft.Automation.json

Hope this helps.

Comment: what could be the values that can be passed instead of null for the sku.family and sku.capacity??? Eventhough those are optional i.e. sku.family and sku.capacity may or may not be used for creation????

Comment: As document described, you can use the string value for sku.family, use integer value for sku.capacity. Also it is optional to create them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745716/azure-arm-template-and-powershell-module?newreg=e23f1233ee3a427397b4187884dd5bf1                                                                                                                                          
    Please see the first arm template in the above link . they have used the value "B" for sku.family property. So my question is what are the other inputs that can be passed to sku.family and similarly to sku.capacity????

Comment: It does no affect the automation account.

Comment: what is the use of sku.family and sku.capacity in the creation of resources in general????

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Automation, SKU-Family and SKU-Capacity are unrequired and are more or less placeholders - "null" accepted.
SKu-name is the only required property of type "[SKuNameEnum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/automationaccount/createorupdate#skunameenum)" with 2 possible values: "Basic" & "Free"
Here are 2 sample responses showing all 3 SKU object properties and you will notice family & capacity are both "null" 
[image]

For your reference, there's a [public facing API Browser page (in preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/) that enumerates all supported REST APIs including API properties, description, usage and response samples. Simply enter the Azure service you would like to explore in the dropdown and drill through the listed APIs. In most cases, It includes a "Tryit" workflow to test the API call.

[image]
Hope this helps.